# Angular momentum (geometric interpretation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Angular momentum is constant along any solution curve in a central force field. What is the geometric meaning of this statement?

Comment: It is [Kepler's Second Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Second_law): the area swept by the radius in a unit of time stays constant.

Comment: This can be understood as a special case of Noether's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) which tells you that conservation of angular momentum corresponds to rotational symmetry (which a central force guarantees). Similarly conservation of momentum corresponds to translational symmetry and conservation of energy corresponds to time symmetry.